# R, ggplot2,unique labels on bar plots (based on factors)

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

So, I would like to label my bars uniquely to show which color describes which level. I've tried the aggregate solution suggested here [How to create unique labels for multiple rows in geom_text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800430/how-to-create-unique-labels-for-multiple-rows-in-geom-text), but it didn't worked.
this is a small dput extract from my data:

```
    testdata2<-structure(list(time = c(4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), days = c(44L, 69L, 69L, 62L, 44L, 62L, 62L, 69L, 44L, 69L, 
62L, 62L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 62L, 
44L, 62L, 69L, 69L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 62L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 44L, 69L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 69L, 
62L, 69L, 69L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 
69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 62L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 
44L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 62L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
69L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 62L, 
69L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 62L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 
44L, 69L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 69L, 69L, 
69L, 62L, 69L, 44L, 62L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 69L, 69L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L), value = c(15428463.1, 8275663.387, 6001381.183, 5851384.572, 
5504593.565, 5473207.122, 5433888.106, 3555472.492, 3311864.32, 
2878210.281, 2235464.82, 2043159.083, 2028397.199, 1977864.446, 
1700550.537, 1528101.872, 1460917.685, 1370737.581, 1312540.266, 
965378.0136, 862158.8019, 823795.2483, 534023.7474, 505910.3843, 
499708.9577, 455411.069, 359275.5795, 311692.5686, 311121.3589, 
308866.8563, 307202.181, 294260.8732, 291732.6364, 285420.0293, 
255216.1535, 250249.7888, 246642.5843, 246191.6839, 234919.1708, 
223646.658, 197494.4277, 195660.3706, 167734.9935, 120841.3395, 
117685.04, 109693.0586, 77103.9889, 75751.28739, 74849.48627, 
68987.77952, 66484.88279, 65769.99157, 65380.57539, 64027.87389, 
59518.86864, 53305.89636, 50951.75888, 44062.09922, 43737.35027, 
43608.36398, 41031.94726, 36667.06157, 35029.66932, 33277.66957, 
32969.54289, 30740.32225, 29759.4345, 29308.53376, 27504.93187, 
26450.97492, 26152.23002, 24348.62813, 23446.82701, 22995.92662, 
21568.85988, 21260.73321, 20952.60682, 19839.62288, 18486.92138, 
17134.21987, 17134.21987, 16442.49783, 16442.49783, 16330.70811, 
16232.41875, 15781.51837, 15727.60661, 14428.81651, 13977.91613, 
13582.93295, 13527.01574, 13076.11501, 13076.11501, 12868.04173, 
12153.1505, 11723.4135, 11438.25928, 11272.51312, 10821.61238, 
10821.61238, 10821.61238, 10476.30327, 10370.712, 10370.712, 
9860.0502, 9551.923524, 9468.91088, 9468.91088, 9468.91088, 9468.91088, 
9468.91088, 9468.91088, 9293.585873, 9293.585873, 9243.797134, 
9018.010496, 9018.010496, 8935.670458, 8935.670458, 7665.308992, 
7665.308992, 7214.408256, 7214.408256, 7148.91221, 6778.784584, 
6778.784584, 6763.507872, 6763.507872, 6470.657908, 6434.020989, 
6312.607136, 6312.607136, 6162.531518, 5854.404842, 5854.404842, 
5719.129768, 5719.129768, 5719.129768, 5546.278166, 5546.278166, 
5546.278166, 5004.238547, 4930.0251, 4509.005248, 4289.347326, 
4058.104512, 4058.104512, 4058.104512, 4058.104512, 4005.645358, 
3697.518968, 3607.204128, 3607.204128, 3607.204128, 3607.204128
), genus = structure(c(78L, 22L, 28L, 64L, 60L, 22L, 60L, 60L, 
64L, 64L, 28L, 78L, 12L, 39L, 78L, 78L, 61L, 39L, 39L, 72L, 41L, 
41L, 12L, 28L, 78L, 72L, 41L, 72L, 22L, 11L, 16L, 63L, 26L, 1L, 
16L, 16L, 5L, 30L, 57L, 23L, 78L, 78L, 36L, 66L, 12L, 35L, 49L, 
69L, 50L, 40L, 26L, 63L, 53L, 24L, 18L, 1L, 15L, 59L, 31L, 18L, 
1L, 47L, 35L, 78L, 5L, 59L, 76L, 58L, 62L, 5L, 8L, 55L, 4L, 77L, 
15L, 2L, 40L, 65L, 1L, 6L, 78L, 11L, 40L, 26L, 78L, 52L, 78L, 
33L, 32L, 47L, 14L, 29L, 63L, 1L, 74L, 54L, 25L, 21L, 42L, 46L, 
79L, 30L, 9L, 13L, 75L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 20L, 37L, 67L, 68L, 2L, 
4L, 29L, 2L, 19L, 25L, 74L, 3L, 27L, 1L, 44L, 27L, 10L, 18L, 
45L, 51L, 27L, 36L, 43L, 70L, 20L, 4L, 73L, 20L, 29L, 77L, 1L, 
43L, 71L, 75L, 13L, 38L, 71L, 17L, 25L, 78L, 78L, 44L, 1L, 1L, 
34L, 48L, 56L), .Label = c("", "Achromobacter", "Acinetobacter", 
"Aeromonas", "Ahrensia", "Algoriphagus", "Aquabacterium", "Arcobacter", 
"Arthrobacter", "Aureimonas", "BAL58-marine-group", "Blastomonas", 
"Bradyrhizobium", "Brevundimonas", "Caulobacter", "Cupriavidus", 
"Defluviicoccus", "Defluviimonas", "Diplosphaera", "Dokdonella", 
"Dyadobacter", "Ferrovibrio", "Flavobacterium", "Fluviicola", 
"Gemmobacter", "GKS98-freshwater-group", "Haematobacter", "Hoeflea", 
"Hyphomonas", "Kerstersia", "Ketogulonicigenium", "Kordiimonas", 
"Lentibacter", "Limnobacter", "Limnohabitans", "Loktanella", 
"Marinomonas", "Marivita", "Massilia", "Mesorhizobium", "Methylotenera", 
"Nisaea", "Nitratireductor", "Novosphingobium", "Oceanibaculum", 
"Oceanisphaera", "Ochrobactrum", "OM43-clade", "Opitutus", "Owenweeksia", 
"Paracocccus", "Parapusillimonas", "Pedobacter", "Peredibacter", 
"Perlucidibaca", "Phyllobacterium", "Polaribacter", "Pseudoalteromonas", 
"Pseudolabrys", "Pseudomonas", "Pseudorhodobacter", "Pseudospirillum", 
"Rhizobium", "Rhodobacter", "Roseicitreum", "Roseivirga", "Roseobacter-clade-CHAB-I-5-lineage", 
"SAR92-clade", "Seohaeicola", "Shinella", "Sphingomonas", "Sphingopyxis", 
"Sphingorhabdus", "Stappia", "Terrimonas", "Thalassobaculum", 
"Thalassospira", "uncultured", "Undibacterium"), class = "factor"), 
    family = structure(c(33L, 34L, 28L, 33L, 31L, 34L, 31L, 31L, 
    33L, 33L, 28L, 34L, 37L, 27L, 34L, 34L, 33L, 27L, 27L, 37L, 
    20L, 20L, 37L, 28L, 33L, 37L, 20L, 37L, 34L, 12L, 8L, 32L, 
    3L, 23L, 8L, 8L, 28L, 3L, 17L, 17L, 10L, 33L, 33L, 16L, 37L, 
    12L, 26L, 33L, 13L, 28L, 3L, 32L, 36L, 13L, 33L, 1L, 10L, 
    39L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 28L, 39L, 34L, 30L, 24L, 
    28L, 9L, 22L, 2L, 34L, 10L, 3L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 14L, 13L, 
    12L, 28L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 10L, 33L, 19L, 7L, 10L, 18L, 32L, 
    1L, 33L, 5L, 33L, 15L, 34L, 2L, 27L, 3L, 21L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 
    25L, 12L, 40L, 24L, 33L, 29L, 3L, 2L, 18L, 3L, 26L, 33L, 
    33L, 22L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 33L, 4L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
    28L, 32L, 40L, 2L, 37L, 40L, 18L, 34L, 1L, 28L, 37L, 11L, 
    6L, 33L, 37L, 34L, 33L, 3L, 18L, 37L, 38L, 1L, 8L, 20L, 28L
    ), .Label = c("", "Aeromonadaceae", "Alcaligenaceae", "Aurantimonadaceae", 
    "Bacteriovoracaceae", "Bradyrhizobiaceae", "Brucellaceae", 
    "Burkholderiaceae", "Campylobacteraceae", "Caulobacteraceae", 
    "Chitinophagaceae", "Comamonadaceae", "Cryomorphaceae", "Cyclobacteriaceae", 
    "Cytophagaceae", "Flammeovirgaceae", "Flavobacteriaceae", 
    "Hyphomonadaceae", "Kordiimonadaceae", "Methylophilaceae", 
    "Micrococcaceae", "Moraxellaceae", "NS11-12-marine-group", 
    "Oceanospirillaceae", "OPB56", "Opitutaceae", "Oxalobacteraceae", 
    "Phyllobacteriaceae", "Porticoccaceae", "Pseudoalteromonadaceae", 
    "Pseudomonadaceae", "Rhizobiaceae", "Rhodobacteraceae", "Rhodospirillaceae", 
    "SHWN-night2", "Sphingobacteriaceae", "Sphingomonadaceae", 
    "uncultured", "Xanthobacteraceae", "Xanthomonadaceae"), class = "factor"), 
    order = structure(c(22L, 23L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 23L, 20L, 20L, 
    22L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 5L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 5L, 5L, 26L, 
    15L, 15L, 26L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 15L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 5L, 21L, 
    5L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 21L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 22L, 22L, 10L, 26L, 
    5L, 19L, 22L, 11L, 21L, 5L, 21L, 25L, 11L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 
    21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 5L, 7L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 3L, 18L, 
    21L, 6L, 20L, 2L, 23L, 7L, 5L, 21L, 22L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 5L, 
    21L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 22L, 14L, 21L, 7L, 7L, 21L, 1L, 22L, 
    4L, 22L, 10L, 23L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 21L, 25L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 
    27L, 18L, 22L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 
    24L, 26L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 27L, 
    2L, 26L, 27L, 7L, 23L, 1L, 21L, 26L, 25L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 
    23L, 22L, 5L, 7L, 26L, 12L, 17L, 5L, 15L, 21L), .Label = c("", 
    "Aeromonadales", "Alteromonadales", "Bdellovibrionales", 
    "Burkholderiales", "Campylobacterales", "Caulobacterales", 
    "Cellvibrionales", "Chlorobiales", "Cytophagales", "Flavobacteriales", 
    "Gaiellales", "Hot-Creek-32", "Kordiimonadales", "Methylophilales", 
    "Micrococcales", "oca12", "Oceanospirillales", "Opitutales", 
    "Pseudomonadales", "Rhizobiales", "Rhodobacterales", "Rhodospirillales", 
    "Rickettsiales", "Sphingobacteriales", "Sphingomonadales", 
    "Xanthomonadales"), class = "factor"), class = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
    2L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 
    10L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 10L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 
    2L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Actinobacteria", 
    "Alphaproteobacteria", "ARKICE-90", "Betaproteobacteria", 
    "Chlorobia", "Cytophagia", "Deltaproteobacteria", "Epsilonproteobacteria", 
    "Flavobacteriia", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Opitutae", "Sphingobacteriia", 
    "Thermoleophilia"), class = "factor"), phylum = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", 
    "Chlorobi", "Proteobacteria", "Verrucomicrobia"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"days", "value", "genus", "family", "order", "class", "phylum"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -155L))
```

the code for a simple bar plot looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
test<-ggplot(testdata2, aes(x =days, y = value, fill=order))+       
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=order,vjust=0.5),position="stack",size=2)+
    theme(legend.position='none')
test
```

as you can see, the "order" labels appear multiple times, which is correct, but not wanted. Is there a simple solution to this in ggplot2 itself or do I have to clean up the data frame beforehand? I tried unique() and subset() in the ggplot call, but I got error messages of having the wrong length.

thanks a lot

Comment: If there are multiple `order`s per row, which y-value to do you want to plot the label at?

Comment: @ZachLipp: hm that is not that easy to answer. it could be at the top as missuse has shown in his response or in the center of the assigned part of the bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach to clean things up.

sum the value across order and days - this will remove the repetition of order

filter out low values to remove labeling something that is so minute that the fill can be barely seen on the graph.

```
library(tidiverse)
testdata2 %>%
  group_by(order, days) %>%
  summarise(val_sum = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(days = as.factor(days)) %>%
  filter(val_sum > 500000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = days, y = val_sum, fill=order))+       
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=order, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1), position="stack",size=3)+
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

without the filtering:

```
testdata2 %>%
  group_by(order, days) %>%
  summarise(val_sum = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(days = as.factor(days)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = days, y = val_sum, fill=order))+       
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=order, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1), position="stack",size=3)+
  theme(legend.position='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! The %>% means something like your "pushing" data "from the lefthandside" into the ggplot call, right?

Comment: %>% is called a pipe. It is from the package [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) it provides a way to program from left to right and not from the inside out in R. It takes some time to get used to but it produces cleaner code (easier to read and debug) and eventually speeds up your coding quite a bit. It is used heavily in `tidyverse` which is a popular set of packages for data wrangling.